# Javascript function depending on random string

Tags: javascript, string, random

First of all thank you for helping newbies like me. My problem is that I have to create a (supposed to be) simple game for a class. A random hour is displayed, and children have to click on the right image corresponding to that time of the day (basically sunrise/sunset, day, and night). If they don't pick the right image, it's replaced by another. If the answer is right, the image stays the same.

```
<body>

<div id="container">

            <input type="image" id="moment1" src="soleil.png" alt="leve-couche-soleil" onclick="bon1()" style="display:inline">

            <input type="image" id="moment2" src="nuit.png" alt="nuit" onclick="bon2()" style="display:inline">

            <input type="image" id="moment3" src="jour.png" alt="jour" onclick="bon3()" style="display:inline">

            <input type="image" id="gris1" src="gris_leve_couche-soleil.png" onclick="bon1()" style="display:none">

            <input type="image" id="gris1" src="gris_nuit.png" onclick="bon2()" style="display:none">

            <input type="image" id="gris1" src="gris_jour.png" onclick="bon3()" style="display:none">

</div>

<div id="js">
<script>

    var heuresmoment1 = ['19 heures', '20 heures', '6 heures', '7 heures', '21 heures', '22 heures', '23 heures', 'minuit', '1 heure', '2 heures', '3 heures', '4 heures', '5 heures', '8 heures', '9 heures', '10 heures', '11 heures', 'midi' ,'13 heures', '14 heures', '15 heures', '16 heures', '17 heures', '18 heures'];

    var mom1 = heuresmoment1.slice(0, 3);

    var mom2 = heuresmoment1.slice(4, 12);

    var mom3 = heuresmoment1.slice(13, 23);

    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * heuresmoment1.length);

    var Consigne = ['Il est '];

    document.write(Consigne + (heuresmoment1[randomIndex]).bold() + '.');

    var img1 = document.getElementById("moment1");
    var img2 = document.getElementById("moment2");
    var img3 = document.getElementById("moment3");

 function bon1() {
        if(randomIndex.value == mom1.value) {
            moment1.style.display = 'inline';
            gris1.style.display = 'none';
        }
        else {
            moment1.style.display = 'none';
            gris1.style.display = 'inline';
        }
    }

 function bon2() {
        if(randomIndex.value == mom2.value) {
            moment2.style.display = 'inline';
            gris2.style.display = 'none';
        }
        else {
            moment1.style.display = 'none';
            gris2.style.display = 'inline';
        }
    }

 function bon3() {
        if(randomIndex.value == mom3.value) {
            moment3.style.display = 'inline';
            gris3.style.display = 'none';
        }
        else {
            moment3.style.display = 'none';
            gris3.style.display = 'inline';
        }
    }

</script>
</div>


</body>
```

I managed to display random hours, but my code for changing the image according to the random hour doesn't work. I don't get any error messages, it just doesn't change anything.

Comment: I don't mean to be harsh, but your logic is all wrong : (

Comment: `randomIndex` is just an index, an integer, there is no `randomIndex.value`. Also, mom1, mom2, and mom3 are arrays of strings. There is no `mom1.value` aswell. Debug it, and you will see it is returning `undefined`

Comment: To check if a string is inside an array of strings, you can do it like this:  `mom1.indexOf('19 heures') === -1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And welcome to StackOverflow.

You must rethink your logic, you have too much `function`which do the same thing.
I refactor your code differently and i hope it helps you ;)

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jcqjmt37/)